# Google API to retrieve Google Sites in Google App account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps

Is there any way of using Google App Scripts to retrieve all the google sites owned by my google app users? Been looking through Google App Scripts and application APIs, but will be good to tap on some expertise in this area. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the documentation?
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sitesapp

For example:

```
SitesApp.getSites("yourdomain.com");
```